# How can I know if all the text is selected in a TRichEdit when the text has three or more lines?

Tags: delphi, richedit, delphi-10.4-sydney

I have a TRichEdit with some [RTF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format) in it (text with formatting only) and I want to know if all the content of the TRichEdit is selected. To do so, I do:

```
var AllSelectd: Boolean;
//...
AllSelectd := MyRichEdit.SelLength = MyRichEdit.GetTextLen;
```

which works fine, except when the content has three lines or more. With zero to two lines, everything is fine. As soon as I reach three lines in my TRichEdit, the code above no longer works (`MyRichEdit.SelLength < MyRichEdit.GetTextLen`). Each line is terminated with CRLF (`#13#10`).

Is this a bug? How can I reliably check if everything is selected in the TRichEdit?

I use Delphi 10.4, if it changes anything.

Comment: Moreover, if we have single line without carriage return, sellength is larger by 1. [Same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725457/richedit-2-0s-usage-of-single-cr-character-as-linebreak-throws-off-selstart-cal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725457/richedit-2-0s-usage-of-single-cr-character-as-linebreak-throws-off-selstart-cal), RichEdit 2.0 replaces CRLF pairs with CR internally, and retrieves LF's in some cases.

As workaround - calculate number of lines in selected range to make correction (`SelText` contains only CR's, `GetTextLen` works with text with retrieved CRLF, so counts both CR's and LF's). Remy Lebeau proposal is used.

```
var
  sel, getl, crcnt, i: integer;
  tx: string;
begin
  sel := RichEdit1.SelLength;
  getl := RichEdit1.GetTextLen;
  crcnt := SendMessage(Richedit1.Handle, EM_EXLINEFROMCHAR, 0, sel);
  Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('%d %d',[sel, getl - crcnt + 1]));
end;
```

Comment: If you are going to retrieve the `SelText` anyway and grab its `Length()`, there is little point in retrieving the `SelLength` as well. On the other hand, have you considered using `EM_EXGETSEL` with `EM_EXLINEFROMCHAR` to calculate the number of lines in the selection without retrieving the actual text?

Comment: @Remy Lebeau You are right. Seems that just using EM_EXLINEFROMCHAR with range 0..SelLength is enough

Comment: @Remy Lebeau I understand, but seems problem `all the text is selected` is solved with `0..SelLength` too

Comment: `EM_EXLINEFROMCHAR` returns a line index, but you are treating it as a character index, subtracting it from the text length. I assume you are doing that to subtract `LF`s from `CRLF` pairs, yes? The whole point of me suggesting `EM_EXLINEFROMCHAR` was to help *count lines* in the selection to offset the `SelText` length. Now I'm thinking this is not necessary at all, I would expect using `EM_EXGETSEL` by itself and then checking `rng.cpMin==0 && rng.cpMax==GetTextLen()` to work.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau About charrange difference - no, error remains. For 5 one-symbol lines cpMin=0, cpMax=10, but GetTextLen is 13

Comment: @Remy Lebeau Yes, I subtract line index (as carriage return count) from text length to compensate lack of LF's

Comment: MBo & @RemyLebeau clever solution, thanks!